# how to prove that estimator converges to posterior distribution

Tags: bayesian, posterior, importance-sampling

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots X_n \sim f(x|\theta)$, $\theta$ has prior $\pi$. Generate $\theta_1, ... \theta_m$ from $\pi$, calculate $q_i = L(\theta_i|\textbf{x}) / \sum_j L(\theta_j|\textbf{x})$ where $L(\theta|\textbf{x}) = \prod_i f(x_i|\theta)$.

Generate $\theta_1^*, \dots \theta_r^*$ where $P(\theta^* = \theta_i) = q_i$. Given that $P(\theta^* \le t)$ converges to $\int_{-\infty}^t \pi(\theta|x) d\theta$, how do we show that estimator $\sum_{j=1}^r h(\theta_j^*)/r$ converges to $E[h(\theta)|x]$ where the expectation is with respect to the posterior distribution?

I know that
\begin{align}
&\sum_{j=1}^r h(\theta_j^*)/r \\
&=\sum_{j=1}^r h(\theta_j)/r \cdot q_j \\
&=\sum_{j=1}^r h(\theta_j)/r \cdot L(\theta_j | x) / \sum_i L(\theta_i|x) \\
&=  \frac{1/r \cdot \sum_{j=1}^r h(\theta_j) \cdot L(\theta_j | x)}{\sum_i L(\theta_i|x) }
\end{align}
If I send $r$ to infinity, the numerator becomes an expectation but the denominator goes to infinity...

Comment: How do $n$ and $r$ relate to each other?  Also note that $\sum_iL(\theta_j|x)$ makes no sense, the indices don't match.

Comment: fixed the likelihood indices. I'm actually not sure how $n$ and $r$ are related...